# Custom next and prev button in material ui pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I want to use "next" and "prev" text instead of next and prev icon in material-ui pagination. I didn't find any prop for the same. Can you guys give me some workaround.

Comment: In their documentation, they have a custom pagination section here: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#custom-pagination-actions. You would change the IconButtons to just normal Buttons with text.

Comment: This is a table Pagination, I am talking about only Pagination component

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the material-ui library for React? Or is it a special library? If it is not material-ui (material-ui.com), please remove the tag and link to the library you are using for pagination.

Comment: It's a material ui component https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/, thats why I have included the tag.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to add the an :after and :before pseudo selector. Here's a code snippet using SCSS.

Make sure to add the pseudo selector to the button, in case you want it to be clickable.

```
 .MuiPagination-root {
   .MuiPagination-ul {
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      li {
        &:first-child {
          flex-basis: 100%;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-start;
          align-items: center;
          > button::after {
            margin-left: 10px;
            content: 'previous';
          }
        }
        &:last-child {
          flex-basis: 100%;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-end;
          align-items: center;
          > button::before {
            margin-right: 10px;
            content: 'next';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use after and before pseudo selectors. For adding styles to buttons, you can use styled function. Styled function returns @mui component with custom styles. [Click here to see docs.](https://mui.com/system/styled/)

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { Pagination } from "@mui/material";
const PaginationContainer = () => {

      const StyledPagination = styled(Pagination)({
            "& .MuiPagination-ul li:last-child": {
                marginLeft: "16px",
            },
            "& .MuiPagination-ul li:last-child button::before": {
                content: "'Next'",
                marginRight: "8px",
            },
            "& .MuiPagination-ul li:first-child": {
                marginRight: "16px",
            },
            "& .MuiPagination-ul li:first-child button::after": {
                content: "'Previous'",
                marginLeft: "8px",
            }
      });
    
      return <StyledPagination count={10} />
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the renderItem prop of the MUI pagination to render a PaginationItem which you can use to customize the next/previous button through the slot prop. The slots props of the PaginationItem has the following properties

```
  slots?: {
    first?: React.ElementType;
    last?: React.ElementType;
    next?: React.ElementType;
    previous?: React.ElementType;
  };
```

So, you can pass any element of your type to override the default MUI element.. See example below

```
<Pagination
          count={10}
          onChange={handlePagination}
          variant="outlined"
          renderItem={(item) => (
            <PaginationItem
              slots={{
                previous: () => (
                  <Typography variant="label">Previous</Typography>
                ),
                next: () => (
                  <Typography variant="label" sx={{ padding: "0 12px" }}>
                    Next
                  </Typography>
                ),
              }}
              {...item}
            />
```